# How to make an image with %2F in the url appear when shared, after including it in html meta og:image tag?

Tags: html, firebase-storage, meta-tags, urlencode, share-open-graph

I have an image stored in Firebase Storage.
I used the link for my website's meta og:image tag, but it doesn't appear on the preview for WhatsApp or Facebook.

It seems like the %2F characters are being replaced with %252F.

How can I get around this issue without changing the name of the image?

[This](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/happie-fea92.appspot.com/o/child_on_desolate_background.jpeg?alt=media&token=c2da9501-5a45-42c0-bb61-cbab901a31fa&_gl=1*1ty3doa*_ga*NjY2MjMzNTMxLjE2NTQ1MTAyMTI.*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTY4NjAzNTUwNi4xMC4xLjE2ODYwMzU5OTcuMC4wLjA.) image works (doesn't have %2F).

[This](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/happie-fea92.appspot.com/o/article_images%2FCreating%20Good%20Habits%2Fcreating_good_habits_association.png?alt=media&token=5035b7e4-6df3-4816-9912-01f67ce4415f&_gl=1*1isjpac*_ga*NjY2MjMzNTMxLjE2NTQ1MTAyMTI.*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTY4NjAzMzIyOS45LjEuMTY4NjAzMzIzNi4wLjAuMA..) image doesn't work (has %2F).

Answer (score 0):

The `%2F` character sequence is the [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding) of a `/` (slack) character. It is used in URLs where having a literal `/` is not allowed, or where it cause problems/misinterpretation of the value.

Whenever a URL encoding (or any other encoding) is applies, the result should be decoded before interpreting it as an original value. That steps seems to be  be missing here, so I suggest decoding the encoded URL in the place where you can't access it.

Comment: Since the encoding and decoding process happens on WhatsApp / Facebook, I cannot affect this. So I guess the only solution is to save the image in the root folder of the Firebase Storage so that the `%2F` character doesn't appear in the name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, it turns out that the problem was that the image size was too big (~500kb). Once I got it down to ~150kb, the image preview worked.

I also used opengraph.xyz to check the image URL generated. Yesterday I saw `%2F` characters being replaced with `%252F`. But today they weren't. I'm not sure what happened. I did use Facebook's debugger tool to scrape the site manually. Perhaps that helped.